# File Upload not Working in Jenkins when script run as service (Selenium/Java)

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, file-upload

The application in which i work needs file upload. The code works fine when the code is run from Eclipse. When I run  the same code in Jenkins (Windows Service). I get, org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: invalid argument: File not found error message

The reason we had to use Jenkins as a service is because, of Network Group Policy and there is no way we can ask Jenkins to run from Command Prompt.

I am unable to fix the issue because, I am not sure whats going on the background as the browser is not visible

Here is the Code snipped to upload file and the error message when we run it from Jenkins.

**Code :**

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='textfield']")));
WebElement filePath = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='textfield']"));

filePath.sendKeys("\\\\XXXXXFOLDER\\data\\SHARED\\PCDEV\\STAFF\\QA_Staff\\ITL
\\FileForXXXXX\\XXX_XXXX_XXXXAPPS.txt");

Thread.sleep(5000);

//Step 8 - Verify user can click the Add File button and display the file name in the text box on the Send Files page

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//* 
[@id='wrapper']/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]
/input[2]")).click();
```

**Error Message:**

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: invalid argument:

File not found: 
\\XXXXXFOLDER\data\SHARED\PCDEV\STAFF\QA_Staff\ITL\FileForXXXXX\XXX_XXXX_XXXXAPPS.txt

Comment: Jenkins retrieve complete source code from repo/hub and stores in its Jenkins user directory located at JENKINS_HOME (Usually at C:/users/<user-name>/.jenkins). Once you get all source code here, try giving path of file from here itself for next Jenkins run.

Answer (score 0):

After WebDriver creation, just add the below line of code in your script.

```
driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
```

It helps to upload the expected file from the local environment to the remote environment.

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue, I tried with AutoIT and robot enter also, not worked for me also, but by using sendKeys working fine, give xpath or id of input tag, may be it works

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys(filePath);

Comment: If the input field for file upload is not available in that case what to do? any other way?